# Create a tag upon every build of the application?

Tags: svn

Do anyone do this in ANT Build. Meaning everytimie a certain target is called e.g. build-sit. A tag will be created in the svn respositoyr to reference to that particular sit version.

Any idea how to do about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html

it is eays to integrate.